# Why javascript doesn't parse this string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I pass json encoded value from PHP to Javascript and just console log it it returns me this:

```
﻿{"id":"4","username":"muzikant346","coins":"675","avatar1":"1","avatar2":"0","avatar3":"0","avatar4":"0","avatar_selected":"0"}
```

This is a string and when I want to parse it in Javascript it returns an error:

```
eUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (welcome.js:11)
at c (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

I don't understand why javascript can't parse this.

There is my PHP (fetch from database) code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM serbian_values WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $value[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($value[0]); 
        }
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: on the above response, `JSON.parse()` works fine

Comment: @AlwaysSunny — No, it doesn't. There is a `U+FEFF : ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE [BOM] {BOM, ZWNBSP}` before the first `U+007B : LEFT CURLY BRACKET {left brace}`: https://jsbin.com/xabezuwura/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `obj='{"id":"4","username":"muzikant346","coins":"675","avatar1":"1","avatar2":"0","avatar3":"0","avatar4":"0","avatar_selected":"0"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));`

Comment: @AlwaysSunny — Of course it works if you *delete* that character

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — It hasn't been escaped. It's a **zero width** non-breaking space. It's naturally invisible.

Comment: Yeah got it, an invisible and unnecessary `.`  exists

Answer (score 1):

A `U+FEFF : ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE [BOM] {BOM, ZWNBSP}` is not a valid character to start a JSON text with.

Somewhere it is getting inserted into the start of the output of the PHP program (or mixed in before parsing in the JS you haven't shown us, but that is less likely).

Possibly this is used by the wrong `charset` appearing on the `Content-Type` header you are outputting from PHP, but the character is probably just lurking in the source code somewhere. It would probably be easiest to find with a hex editor.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix that first BOM character,

```js
function stripBOM(content) {
  content = content.toString()
  if (content.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
    content = content.slice(1)
  }
  return content
}

console.log(JSON.parse(stripBOM(obj)));
```

**Ref.** https://gist.github.com/pbakondy/f5045eff725193dad9c7

Comment: Another ref: https://gist.github.com/antic183/619f42b559b78028d1fe9e7ae8a1352d

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.parse` can only parse `string` elements. One solution is to stringify your JSON first:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"id":"4","username":"muzikant346","coins":"675","avatar1":"1","avatar2":"0","avatar3":"0","avatar4":"0","avatar_selected":"0"}));
```

Comment: If that was the problem, then the error message would be about an unexpected token `o` and not a zero width non-breaking space.